# How do I make my website communicate with a rasperry pi

Tags: python, php, html, raspberry-pi

If anyone have ever used PiSignage you know they have some advanced features like 'Take screenshot', 'Shell frame' etc. What I want is to make my own digital signage system like pisignage. I want to have a button on my website and when I click on  it, it tells my RaspberryPI player to take a screenshot and send it back to the website. What should I lookup to find documentation about this?

Comment: Is the website going to run on the Pi, or another machine?

Comment: My website is currently hosted on my own local Windows computer.

Comment: Ok. And what about the piSignage control system? Are you using a local server or the hosted solution? Also, what is the purpose of taking a screenshot exactly? If you simply want to know what the player is displaying at that moment, the API might be able to help you already: https://piathome.com/apidocs/

Comment: I've change the post now. What i want is to make my own digital signage system like PiSignage but i dont know how to make theese advanced features.

Comment: Well, pi-signage server is open-source so you could either a) just use that, since it's MIT-licensed, and build your own client. or b) have a look at the source and see if you can figure out how they did it (or at least part of it).

Comment: If you want to automate your specific media player (which one do you use?) you'd have to check its documentation to see if it has any kind of API which would allow it.

Comment: The only player i have atm. is a raspberry pi

Comment: No, by "player" I meant the specific software on the pi that you're doing to use to display the signage. I assumed you wanted to request an output of whatever is on that software's display at that moment? Or do you just want a screenshot of the entire screen?

Comment: Ohhh i see! Im just showing chromium in kiosk mode with the specific url www.mydomain.com/screen/XXXXXX

Comment: you could just embed that URL in your other web page in an iframe then, and it would show you what's there.

Answer (score 0):

In piSignage we use websocket for communication between server (in your case which serves your website) and the Pi player. When the server requests screenshot over the websocket, player uses https://github.com/AndrewFromMelbourne/raspi2png program to take the screenshot and send back the image.